# Parts for bar lighting

Tags: electrical, home-automation

Looking to build a small dry bar with some lights and not sure I have all compatible parts before I start installing. I have the lutron caseta ecosystem so I will be using those as the dimmer switch.

[Armacost LED Driver for lights](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Armacost-Lighting-120-Watt-Universal-Dimming-Driver-12-Volt/1003246544)

[Armacost LED strip for underneath open wood shelving](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Armacost-Lighting/5013490785)

[Armacost LED recessed light for 1 upper cabinet](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Armacost-Lighting-Gimbal-Recessed-LED-Light-4000K-Brushed-Steel/1003047196)

Does the LED driver work with the lighting selection? Also, I'm not sure if I need the regular [Lutron dimmer](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Lutron-Caseta-Wireless-Single-Pole-3-Way-White-Smart-LED-Decorator-Light-Dimmer/50449012) or the [ELV version](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Lutron-Caseta-Wireless-250-Watt-Single-Pole-White-LED-Smart-Dimmer/1000449717).

Comment: Cant access those links

Comment: @RohitGupta links work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt those LED bulbs have been tested with that particular switch, so YMMV as to functionality.  Are you going to be running 120V cable for the switch and the recessed light?  Do you have a junction box where you can connect your driver?

Note that you have selected a 12V driver, but a 24V light strip.  I'm not sure that the 120V dimmer switch will work on a LED driver, either.

Comment: Our electrician will be supplying the cables/junction box. I'll have to supply the actual smart switch and lights. I accidentally bought a 12V driver, but will switch it to a 24V driver.


Would you have a different setup up for LED strip and recessed light?

Comment: I think you'll have better selection for smart switching if you use all 120V.  But then your wire connections become more complicated, because all splices need to be accessible.  If you had pics of the bar (or sketches if it doesn't yet exist), that would sure help.